# How to detect that a MySQL prepared statement has inserted or updated to stop a while loop in Java 8?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a prepared statement that I wish to run until an insert or update replacing a NULL value occurs. The prepared statement is:

```
String insertQryCAD = ("INSERT INTO at_cub_award_date " +
    "(ca_id, ad_id, cad_task_completion_date) " +
    "VALUES (?, ?, ?) " +
    "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cad_task_completion_date = IF(at_cub_award_date IS NULL, ?, STR_TO_DATE(cad_task_completion_date, '%Y-%m-%d'));");
```

I then want to run something like:

```
ps = c.prepareStatement(insertQryCAD);
int i = 0;
while (i < 4) {
  ps.setString(1, caId);
  ps.setString(2, adId);
  ps.setString(3, attendance);
  ps.setString(4, attendance);
  ps.executeUpdate();
  i++;
}
```

How do I stop the while loop when an (insert) or (update replacing a NULL value) occurs?

Example 1:

```
|Row|Val 1| Val 2| Val 3|Action|
________________________________
| 1 |  1  |  5   |  A   | skip  
________________________________
| 2 |  1  |  6   |  B   | skip  
________________________________
| 3 |  1  |  7   | null | update and stop  
________________________________
| 4 |  1  |  8   |   C  |  
________________________________
```

Example 2:

```
|Row|Val 1| Val 2| Val 3|Action|
________________________________
| 1 |  1  |  5   |  A   | skip  
________________________________
| 2 |  1  |  6   |  B   | skip  
________________________________
No row so Insert and stop  
________________________________
```

I tried:

```
int returnValue = ps.executeUpdate(); 
if (returnValue == 1) { 
    i = 7; 
}else{
    i++;
}
```

The trouble is this always updates in the "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE".

Comment: Check the return value of `executeUpdate()`.

Comment: @shmosel Is this what you mean 
          
          int returnValue = ps7.executeUpdate();
          
          if (returnValue == 1) {
           i = 7;
          }

Comment: @shmosel Tried your suggestion (please see my edited question). However, it always updates, so returnValue is always "1".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There won't be a way to distinguish the number of inserts from the number updates via the result of an `executeUpdate`.  It returns the number of rows *affected*.   That will be 1 row affected in both the insert and update cases.

So if you want to distinguish the insert and update cases, you will need to write the SQL another way.  For example:

- You could do the following in Java

  - start a transaction
  - perform the `INSERT` without the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` part
  - catch a duplicate key exception and perform the `UPDATE`
  - commit the transaction

  keeping track of which path you took in Java code.
- You could call an SQL stored procedure that does the same thing all on the server side.

Note that `ON DUPLICATE KEY` appears to be a MySQL-ism.

Comment: There are other workarounds, like setting a special `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in the ODKU.

Comment: @shmosel - I don't understand what you are suggesting.   (My reading of the Q is that the OP wants to know the whether there was an insert, not what the row id was.)  Could spell out what you mean in your own answer?